# Admob works for interstitial, but not for the banner

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I have updated my App in the Apple Store, I included AdMob.

The interstitial loads and works correctly, however the banner does not seem to load. I think the banner should load because; In the simulator they both worked, they use the same Ad unit ID and above all the interstitial also works.

Does anyone have a suggestion what can be wrong or where I could look to find out any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they use the same Ad unit ID

This is your problem. Each ad needs its own unique Ad unit ID. One Ad unit ID for the interstitial ad, and one Ad unit ID for the banner ad in your case. The reason the interstitial works and the banner does not is because you have the correct Ad unit ID set for your interstitial whereas your banner can not use an interstitial Ad unit ID.

1. Go to [**AdMob.com**](https://apps.admob.com/#home)
2. Click Monetize
3. Click "YourApplicationName"
4. Click New Ad Unit
5. Select **Banner** and follow the setup
6. Implement the newly generated Ad unit ID for your banner in your application